# Best way to implement my own statuses on my custom element type?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I'm working on a plugin with its own element type, I'm trying to add custom statuses to the element type. What is the best way to proceed? I have hasStatuses set to true and getStatuses is where I would set them.. But what should the array look like thats returned?

UserElementType returns this:

```
/**
 * Returns all of the possible statuses that elements of this type may have.
 *
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getStatuses()
{
    return array(
        UserStatus::Active    => Craft::t('Active'),
        UserStatus::Pending   => Craft::t('Pending'),
        UserStatus::Locked    => Craft::t('Locked'),
        UserStatus::Suspended => Craft::t('Suspended'),
        UserStatus::Archived  => Craft::t('Archived')
    );
}
```

Comment: So I did a little bit more research and noticed that the UserStatus is an enum. Is this a possibility to implement in a Craft plugin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need to return from the `getStatuses()` method is an associative `array()` where the key represents the status **name** and the value represents the status **label**, more or less.

An example might be a set of statuses for a **Payment** element type:

```php
public function getStatuses()
{
    return array(
        'captured' => Craft::t('Captured'),
        'canceled' => Craft::t('Canceled'),
        'refunded' => Craft::t('Refunded'),
    );
}
```

Now, since it is likely that you'll be referring to and comparing against those statuses, it makes sense to give yourself a little extra insurance by creating a set of [class constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) instead of using plain strings.

That is exactly what Craft has done in the **UserStatus** class and you can achieve the same result in one of two ways.

---

**1.** Create your own class and define those constants

```php
// plugin/enums/PluginPaymentStatus.php
namespace Craft;

class PluginPaymentStatus
{
    const CAPTURED = 'captured';
    const CANCELED = 'canceled';
    const REFUNDED = 'refunded';
}

// plugin/elementtypes/PluginElementType.php
public function getStatuses()
{
    return array(
        PluginPaymentStatus::CAPTURED => Craft::t('Captured'),
        PluginPaymentStatus::CANCELED => Craft::t('Canceled'),
        PluginPaymentStatus::REFUNDED => Craft::t('Refunded'),
    );
}
```

**2.** Create the status constants in your element type model if you have one

---

Note that if you go with option **1**, you will need to **import|include|require** your **"enum"**.